# Angular - Remove a row after filtering a table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a table with `filter`'s like :

```
ng-repeat="person in filtered = ( data | filter:query | filter : name | filter {m_resource: resourceFilter} | filter : {m_id : idFilter} | limitTo:maxRowSize )"
```

And inside the table as part of each row, I have a `delete` button:

```
<button class ="btn" ng-click="removeRow($data, $index, this)">del</button>
```

when clicking on the `button` I want the `row` to be removed from the `UI`, without using any filter I just use `splice`:

```
$scope.data.splice(index, 1);
```

But when I am applying filter it wont work beacuse the `index`(numer of the row in the displayed table) is the `UI index` not the `data index`.
Anyone know's how to delete a `row` after filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<button class ="btn" ng-click="removeRow(person)">del</button>
```

In your removeRow function,

```
var index = $scope.data.indexOf(person);
$scope.data.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: Trying and posting the result.